# Spark Union Order Issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, union

I have populated data in below format:

```
Ref_Data1 Ref_Data2 Tak_Data1 Tak_Data2 Id
   a         b         c         d       1
   e         f         g         h       2
```

The Id column is populated using the monotonically_increasing_id()

Finally I am trying to union Ref_ and Tak_ columns, where the Id column value would stay same for different rows if they belonged to same row before union, for identifying them as a pair later by API.

The expected output is like below:

```
Data1 Data2 Id
  a    b     1
  c    d     1
  e    f     2
  g    h     2
```

As soon as I do the union it messes up the order and I get something like below:

```
Data1 Data2 Id
  a    b     1
  c    d     2
  e    f     1
  g    h     2
```

How can I preserve the order for my rows while doing the union.

Comment: whats stopping you to use `orderBy(Id)`

Comment: @Vaebhav- Order is not the issue. Id's getting assigned to wrong rows is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Union works well , and I do not see data mismatch, you can further edit your question and add the code snippets you have developed so far.

**Union requires you to have consistent column orders through the dataframe(s)**

## Input Data

```
input_str = """
Ref_Data1 Ref_Data2 Tak_Data1 Tak_Data2
   a         b         c         d     
   e         f         g         h     
"""

input_values = list(map(lambda x : x.strip(),input_str.split()))

columns = input_values[:4]

input_list = [tuple(input_values[4:8])
             ,tuple(input_values[8:])
             ]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list,columns)

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('Id',F.monotonically_increasing_id())

sparkDF.show()

+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|Ref_Data1|Ref_Data2|Tak_Data1|Tak_Data2|        Id|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|        a|        b|        c|        d|         0|
|        e|        f|        g|        h|8589934592|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
```

## Union

```
sparkDF_1 = sparkDF.select([F.col('Ref_Data1').alias('Data1'),F.col('Ref_Data2').alias('Data2'),F.col('Id')])
sparkDF_2 = sparkDF.select([F.col('Tak_Data1').alias('Data1'),F.col('Tak_Data2').alias('Data2'),F.col('Id')])


finalDF = sparkDF_1.union(sparkDF_2).orderBy('Id')

finalDF.show()

+-----+-----+----------+
|Data1|Data2|        Id|
+-----+-----+----------+
|    a|    b|         0|
|    c|    d|         0|
|    e|    f|8589934592|
|    g|    h|8589934592|
+-----+-----+----------+
```

Comment: @Vaebhav- your suggested solution is not working for me as of now, I'll try to post my code snippet as soon as possible, but if you replace the Id's that you have inserted manually by monotonically_increasing_id(), then you might notice the issue.

Comment: @Prashant - I see what you mean , I ll try it with dynamically creating the increasing id column , also it would be helpful , if you can post your code snippets as well

Comment: Updated the answer , using `monotonically_increasing_id` rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: This solution works in interactive mode but as soon I push this as spark submit the whole order messes up again.

Comment: Well then, you don’t have to split IDs right after union, only solit it in the next select step

Answer (score 0):

One idea to keep your orders (which is mismatched for some reason, it works fine in my case though), is "zipping" the ID with the row, then you can do whatever you want after that. This way will assure the ID for each row sticks with the row no matter what.

```
df = (spark
    .read
    .csv('a.csv', header=True)
    .withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    .withColumn('Ref_Data1', F.array('Ref_Data1', 'id'))
    .withColumn('Tak_Data1', F.array('Tak_Data1', 'id'))
    .drop('id')
)
# +---------+---------+---------+---------+
# |Ref_Data1|Ref_Data2|Tak_Data1|Tak_Data2|
# +---------+---------+---------+---------+
# |   [a, 0]|        b|   [c, 0]|        d|
# |   [e, 1]|        f|   [g, 1]|        h|
# +---------+---------+---------+---------+

ref = df.select(F.col('Ref_Data1').alias('Data1'), F.col('Ref_Data2').alias('Data2'))
tak = df.select(F.col('Tak_Data1').alias('Data1'), F.col('Tak_Data2').alias('Data2'))

(ref
    .union(tak)
    .select(
        F.col('Data1')[1].alias('id'),
        F.col('Data1')[0].alias('Data1'),
        F.col('Data2')
    )
    .show()
)
# +---+-----+-----+
# | id|Data1|Data2|
# +---+-----+-----+
# |  0|    a|    b|
# |  1|    e|    f|
# |  0|    c|    d|
# |  1|    g|    h|
# +---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: -I'll give this a try and keep you posted. However this seems to become tedious if I have large number of columns. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Technically, you don’t have to zip ID with all columns, just the ones that you’re going to union together. Plus, it’s just a matter of a for loop with different column names

Comment: This solution works in interactive mode but as soon I push this as spark submit the whole order messes up again. In fact it works fine until union but messes up at select which I have as a separate step.

Comment: Another option is after `monotonically_increasing_id`, you can write it down to the database, then read it again and do any union you want, now the IDs will no longer rely on `monotonically_increasing_id`, but rather just a normal ID value

Comment: That's the challenge, intermediately persisting data to hdfs is not permissible, otherwise it was easy.